# Started sticky service have been removed by system

Tags: android, service

I implemented a test service:

```
public class TestService extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Here is code that started the service:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService(new Intent(this, TestService.class));
    }
}
```

I declared service in manifest

```
<service android:name=".TestService"/>
```

After starting the service, I have seen the service process in the Android task manager. I tried kill the process, and the Android restarted it.

I set the device aside for a while. After an hour the service was killed. I didn't see it in the Android task manager.

What am I doing wrong?

My device is Samsung A3 (2016).

Comment: It does not guarantee of restarting of the service in certain conditions   source --> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: How did Viber do it?

Comment: try to restart the service with alarm manager

Comment: I tried using alarm manager onDestroy() and onTaskRemoved(). The service was killed and not restarted.

Comment: What OS version does your device run? What do you mean by "see in android task manager"?

Comment: Android OS 6.0.1. Android have a development utility which shows running tasks and services.